# How to manually create a Z-table

Tags: probability, numerical-methods, normal-distribution

Z-tables are commonly found online. However, I am writing a precision program for this, and so I would like to find out how to calculate my own percentage values.

Comment: You mean from scratch? Robust methods are already built into most mathematical software, such as MATLAB's normcdf function or Excel's NORMDIST function.

Comment: [R's `pnorm`and `qnorm` functions](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Normal.html) are easy to use

Comment: @Henry Yes, but how do the programs calculate it themselves?

Comment: You can see the R source code (in C) at https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/nmath/pnorm.c and https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/nmath/qnorm.c

Comment: I doubt the source for any numerical software for this sort of task is easy to follow, because I'm sure there are multiple hardcoded constants built in.

Comment: ...indeed, before they start actually doing anything of substance, R's source initializes a bunch of arrays of hardcoded constants with no comment about where they came from (beyond the comment about the method being used at the top).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Z-tables are just values of the CDF
$$
F(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{x} e^{-y^{2}/2}dy
$$
at various points $x$. If you want to generate a Z-table, pick some $x$ points and evaluate that integral (using a numerical method of your choice).

As mentioned in the comments to your question, MATLAB (and other numerical software) already do this for you. Probably best not to reinvent the wheel.

---

**Addendum**: As @Ian mentioned, we should truncate the integral since it is on an unbounded domain. That is, we should look to compute instead

$$
F(x)\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{w(x)}^{x}e^{-y^{2}/2}dy.
$$
The question is thus, how do we pick $w(x)$? Let's say that you are only interested in computing the integral up to $\epsilon$ accuracy. Therefore, it might be reasonable to pick $w(x)$ such that
$$
F(w(x))=\frac{1}{2}\text{erfc}(-w(x)/\sqrt{2})\leq\epsilon.
$$
A well-known bound for the erf function is
$$
\text{erfc}(x)\leq e^{-x^{2}}.
$$
Plugging this into the above,
$$
F(w(x))\leq\frac{1}{2}e^{-w(x)^{2}/2}
$$
and thus it follows that
$$
w(x)\leq-\sqrt{-2\log(2\epsilon)}.
$$

> For example, if $\epsilon=10^{-6}$, $w(x)\leq-5.1230$ (approximately). This makes sense, as 5-sigma events should not make much of a contribution in computation.

This bound is **very** conservative, however, and you could/should come up with a tighter one, or one that takes into account relative instead of absolute error (also mentioned in comments).

Comment: Just "evaluate the integral using a numerical method of your choice" is not quite so simple for an integral over an unbounded domain. In this particular case, if I were asked to do it from scratch (in a situation like an interview, not a live environment), I'd ask what error tolerance $\epsilon$ they want to enforce, then find the smallest $M>0$ such that $F(-M)<\epsilon/3$. Then treat the integrals on $(-\infty,-M]$ and $[M,\infty)$ as being zero and use a standard rule (e.g. the trapezoidal rule) on $[-M,M]$, enforcing an error bound of $\epsilon/3$.

Comment: e^{-y^{2}/2}dy is for the graph, yes? And where does 1 over sqrt 2pi come in? Just trying to understand.

Comment: @Solver The factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$ is the normalization constant that makes the integral over the whole line equal to $1$. The proof that this is the right normalization is famous, look up "compute Gaussian integral".

Comment: @Ian Okay. I think I get that. +1

Comment: By the way, even the suggestion I gave has its problems: it keeps the absolute error below $\epsilon$ but the relative error could be very large. Keeping the relative error down requires some kind of asymptotic analysis of the tails of the normal distribution, which is better done analytically or at least partially analytically rather than just numerically.

Comment: An easy-to-prove improvement on your tail analysis can be found at https://mikespivey.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/normaltails/ In short, the tails are bounded above by $\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{x \sqrt{2 \pi}}$ and below by $\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \left ( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^3} \right )$. That doesn't do you much good for reducing the relative error though: you could get an estimate accurate to a relative error of $10^{-12}$ only by taking $M$ on the order of $10^6$, which is rather impractical.

Comment: One can eliminate the tail entirely by exploiting that $F(0) = \frac{1}{2}$. Then $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt = F(0) + \int_0^x f(t) dt$, leaving us with the problem of evaluation an integral over a *finite* interval. A simple course of action is to abandon the integral entirely and instead solve the initial value problem $F'(x) = f(x)$, $F(0) = \frac{1}{2}$ using, say, an explicit Runge-Kutta method. This gives a table which can be to interpolated new values at low cost.

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid >_<

Comment: @CarlChristian That's a nice trick unless you're actually trying to compute a tail (e.g. if you are asked for $F(-6)$). If you try to do that with the tail itself you will get catastrophic cancellation.

Comment: @Iain. The trick is not limited to positive $x$ as $F(-6) = F(0) + \int_0^{-6} f(t) dt = F(0) - \int_{-6}^0 f(t) dt$ shows. 

Par. That was never my intention. Regardless of which flavor of integration we do deploy Richardson extrapolation to get reliable error estimates and determine if rounding error are insignificant or not.

Comment: @CarlChristian You can formulate the trick just as well for positive $x$ as for negative $x$, I agree. However, in floating point arithmetic, $\int_{-6}^0 f(t) dt$ is quite close to $1/2$, so the subtraction suffers from loss of significance. (My point is made a bit better with something more like $-10$ rather than $-6$.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some python code to make your own z-table (in case you find it useful)

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def normalProbabilityDensity(x):
    constant = 1.0 / np.sqrt(2*np.pi)
    return(constant * np.exp((-x**2) / 2.0) )

standard_normal_table = pd.DataFrame(data = [],
                                 index = np.round(np.arange(0, 3.5, .1),2),
                                 columns = np.round(np.arange(0.00, .1, .01), 2))

for index in standard_normal_table.index:
    for column in standard_normal_table.columns:
        z = np.round(index + column, 2)
        value, _ = quad(normalProbabilityDensity, np.NINF, z)
        standard_normal_table.loc[index, column] = value

# Formatting to make the table look like a z-table 
standard_normal_table.index = standard_normal_table.index.astype(str)
standard_normal_table.columns = [str(column).ljust(4,'0') for column in standard_normal_table.columns]
```

I also derived the math explaining how to make it [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-and-create-a-z-table-standard-normal-table-240e21f36e53).

Answer (score 0):

@henry and @user104111 I will share the same answer as the [thread here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1624/based-on-z-score-is-it-possible-to-compute-confidence-without-looking-at-a-z-ta/389082#389082) because I understand what you're saying. You don't want a software or tool to build a table but you need the formula & methods used to create the table from scratch and find the values in it.

So to find the values, you can proceed with more than one methods. You can use the [Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) and approximate each individual value in a [z score table](https://www.ztable.net) for both negative and positive side. Alternatively, you can also use series approximation or numerical integration. As @whuber added in the other thread Mills Ratio works well out in the tails: see stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7200.

Hope this clears your doubts. Feel free to ask if you have any questions and I will elaborate my answer.

Disc: I'm affiliated with the site linked above